# Javascript one page scroll script scroll to every clicked link one after one

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a page divided to a section. It works perfectly except one thing, script scroll page to specific section but If I will hit more than one link it will send me to every clicked link one after one.

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    hash = hash.replace("#", "");

    var elem = jQuery(".pb-line-css-group-" + hash);

    menu_scroll_to(elem);
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(".menu-item A").click(function () {
        var hash = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        hash = hash.replace("#", "");
        hash = hash.replace("/", "");

        var elem = jQuery(".pb-line-css-group-" + hash);

        menu_scroll_to(elem);
    });
});

function menu_scroll_to(elem) {

    if (elem) {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: elem.offset().top - 70
        }, 2000, "easeOutQuint");
    }

}
```

I want to scroll to only first clicked link and if I will hit another link during the scroll in will not scroll to those location

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at some stable solutions such as [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). Trying to reinvent the wheel will just give you much more headaches when you start thinking about touch screen devices, touch laptops, animations performance, cross browser compatibility, old browsers compatibility, callbacks, infinite scrolling, keyboard accessibility, responsiveness... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a special flag, e.g. 'window.scrolling', set it to true before scrolling and to false in callback after scrolling. When user will try to click links it will nothing do while first one is working.